# Storing intermediate values in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, random-walk

I'm trying to simulate a 2-d random walk, with direction 0 < θ < 2π and T=1000 steps.

```
a=np.zeros((1000,1000))

def randwalk(x,y):
    theta=2*math.pi*rd.rand() 
    x+=math.cos(theta);          
    y+=math.sin(theta);          
    return (x,y)
```

How can I store all the intermediate coordinates in a? I was initially trying something of the form:

```
for i in range(1000):
    for j in range(1000):
        a[i,j] = randwalk(x,y)
```

But this doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: why is it a 2d array?

Comment: Your numpy array is the wrong size.  You want `a=np.zeros((1000,2))`, ie, 1000 2D points.  Also, please post a minimal and complete piece of code, that is, something we can cut and paste and run.  For example, in the line `a[i,j]=randwalk(x,y)`, what are `x` and `y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main obvious problem is that you want a 2D array of 1000 points, not a 1000x1000 array.  For example, you say you want to take 1000 steps, but your nested loop takes 1,000,000.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random as rd
import math

a=np.zeros((1000,2), dtype=np.float)

def randwalk(x,y):
    theta=2*math.pi*rd.random() 
    x+=math.cos(theta);          
    y+=math.sin(theta);          
    return (x,y)

x, y = 0., 0.
for i in range(1000):
    x, y = randwalk(x,y)
    a[i,:] = x, y

plt.figure()
plt.plot(a[:,0], a[:,1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like

```
T = 1000
a = [(0,0)] * T

for i in range(1, len(a)):
    a[i] = randwalk(*a[i - 1])
```

No need for numpy here.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a type error.  randwalk is returning a 2-tuple, and you're trying to set an array element where a float is expected.

First of all, you don't want a 1000 by 1000 array.  This would give a million data points, and you only need 2000.  I think what you want is something like this:

```
xs = np.zeros((1000))
ys = np.zeros((1000))
x = 0
y = 0
for i in range(1000):
    xs[i], ys[i] = randwalk()
```

Also, should change the definition of randwalk to take no parameters, and to make x and y global variables:

```
def randwalk():
    global x, y
```

As you have it, you're modifying the values of the parameters, but they aren't accumulated from call to call.